# Why can't I return an explicitly-typed Result enum from a function?

Tags: enums, rust

Simple code as below:

```
fn main() {
    let R1 = TestResult(10, 20);
    match R1 {
        Ok(value) => println!("{}", value),
        Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
    }
}

fn TestResult(a1: i32, a2: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    if a1 > a2 {
        //Compile Pass
        //Ok(100)

        //Compile with error why ?
        std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>::Ok(100)
    } else {
        Err(String::from("Error Happens!"))
    }
}
```

I get the error

```
error: expected one of `!`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `?`, `{`, `}`, or an operator, found `,`
  --> src/main.rs:15:32
   |
15 |         std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>::Ok(100)
   |                                ^ expected one of 8 possible tokens here

error[E0423]: expected value, found enum `std::result::Result`
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>::Ok(100)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: did you mean to use one of the following variants?
           - `std::result::Result::Err`
           - `std::result::Result::Ok`

error[E0423]: expected value, found builtin type `i32`
  --> src/main.rs:15:29
   |
15 |         std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>::Ok(100)
   |                             ^^^ not a value

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
9  | fn TestResult(a1: i32, a2: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
   |                                    ------------------- expected `std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>` because of return type
...
15 |         std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>::Ok(100)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found bool
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<i32, std::string::String>`
              found type `bool`
```

I'm using Rust 1.26.0.

Comment: You should use lowercase for the names of local variables and for the names of methods and functions. For instance `let R1` should be `let r1`. This won't fix your compiler error, but it is better Rust style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's a syntax error. The correct syntax uses the *turbofish* (`::<>`) on the *enum variant*:

```
std::result::Result::Ok::<i32, std::string::String>(100)
```

---

You also *shouldn't* use an explicit type unless you really need it — it's not idiomatic. Rust variables and functions use `snake_case`.

```
fn main() {
    let r1 = test_result(10, 20);
    match r1 {
        Ok(value) => println!("{}", value),
        Err(error) => println!("{}", error),
    }
}

fn test_result(a1: i32, a2: i32) -> Result<i32, String> {
    if a1 > a2 {
        Ok(100)
    } else {
        Err(String::from("Error Happens!"))
    }
}
```